# minikube error - scp: /usr/local/bin/localkube: No space left on device

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to install minikube according to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/) manual.
First I had [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2755) bug so I downgraded minikube to version 0.25.2. Now i'm facing this error:

```
mac:~ username$ minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve --loglevel=0
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Kubernetes version downgrade is not supported. Using version: v1.10.0
Moving files into cluster...
E0504 19:09:14.812623   10018 start.go:234] Error updating cluster:  Error running scp command: sudo scp -t /usr/local/bin output: scp: /usr/local/bin/localkube: No space left on device
: Process exited with status 1
```

My root directory is 100GB free, what am I missing?

Comment: It's referring to the VM that minikube creates and runs the kubernetes machinery on. The virtual disk for that lives in your .minikube directory in your home directory. So delete the .minikube directory and try to do minikube start again.

Comment: thanks a lot, can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: It's the fix for most minikube problems, unfortunately. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

The default disk size for minikube is 2000MB.

Set a new default size for minikube with

```
minikube config set disk-size
```

eg

```
minikube config set disk-size 8000
```

for 8GB (8000 mb)

Then delete your minikube with

```
minikube delete
```

and then start a fresh instance with

```
minikube start
```